# Trying to open an input in PortMidi

Tags: c++, audio, midi

I'm trying to open a midi port to read events from a midi keyboard in C++ using PortMidi. I have found the device id for the keyboard using GetDeviceInfo but can't open the input.

The function looks like this:

```
    Pm_OpenInput    (   PortMidiStream **   stream,
                        PmDeviceID  inputDevice,
                        void *  inputDriverInfo,
                        long    bufferSize,
                        PmTimeProcPtr   time_proc,
                        void *  time_info    
                    )
```

The full documentation behind that function is [here](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/doxygen/group__grp__device.html)

And my implementation...

```
PortMidiStream **stream;
Pm_OpenInput(stream, 12, NULL, 128, NULL, NULL);
```

..gives the error

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'stream' is being used without being initialized.

..which is true enough, as I haven't initialized it. I've looked through PortMidi.h and most of the internet trying to find PortMidiStream and how to initialize it with no success. The header file just has a typedef for it and a comment saying

> A single PortMidiStream is a
>   descriptor for an open MIDI device

which didn't help much.

Any ideas appreciated

Jordan

P.S- Here's the PortMidi download page http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/wiki/portmidi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states

> stream is the address of a
>   PortMidiStream pointer which will
>   receive a pointer to the newly opened
>   stream.

So modify your code to do exactly what it says.

```
PortMidiStream *stream; /* A PortMidiStream pointer */
Pm_OpenInput(&stream, 12, NULL, 128, NULL, NULL); /* Pass the address of the pointer */
```

This is a common idiom in C for returning pointer values.